# Core Data model Is throwing Exception

Tags: iphone, core-data

I  am using core data in my app. My app was working fine.. I recently reset my simulator setting and now that app is throwing exception. I read all posts and clean my target also but it is not running ,,then I set breakPoint and found exception in last line of this code

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {

    if (managedObjectModel_ != nil) {
        return managedObjectModel_;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"TouristGuide" withExtension:@"momd"];
    managedObjectModel_ = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];    
    return managedObjectModel_;
}
```

This code is in my APPdelegate file..  And Exception is

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot create an
>   NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model'

Comment: Do you call `[self managedObjectModel]` in your persistentStoreCoordinator accessor?

Comment: If you have two data model, check which one is active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, the model seems to be nil, or rather the `modelURL`. You can see this by adding `NSLog(@"%@", modelURL)`, it will print `(null)`.

Make sure that your model is really called `TouristGuide` and is in the `mainBundle`, i.e. gets added when building.

Comment: If the name is correct, make sure your .xcdatamodeld file is added in the Compile Sources list (in Xcode 4, click the project on the left, select your target, go to Build Phases and check Compile Sources).

Comment: +1 For some reason, the simulator does not always delete the entire app bundle which sometimes leaves multiple copies of data models and other files. Reseting the simulator fixes the problem.